# Add an event to all Forms in a Project

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, events, ui-automation

If I want to display the size of every `Form` in my Project in the `Form`'s Title what will be the best approach?
I don't want to manually put a event handler in every `Form`.
I want the process to be automatic.
Something like a overloaded `Load()` event that adds a handler on the resize event.

Comment: You can use [Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Automation.Automation);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&view=netframework-4.7.2)) for this. Its `Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler` with a `WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent` raises when a Window (any Window) is opened. You could change a Form title when you detect its been activated. Automation is a bit delicate to handle, though.

Comment: A custom base class that all your forms inherit from would be the best solution. You can have the base class modify the text in, say, the `Shown` event.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  I've searched about this matter and I've actually found nothing about it. It might be interesting to add a couple of solution to this "problem". I could test the Automation pattern in VB.Net.

Comment: @Jimi : It's a matter of simple class inheritance, nothing special really :). All forms already inherit from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`, you just gotta change them to inherit `YourBaseForm` instead.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: Inheritance is not an option. I can't change hundreds of forms.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Yes, but since one of the OP parameters requires that you don't change/edit the existing Forms (one could also use templates when building an UI from scratch), I though that it could be interesting to have a reference if you want to have some kind of *global handler* that allows to add/remove Event Handlers to Top Level Windows *On-the-fly* and modify their behaviour/presentation at run-time, using different tools. Actually, I'ld like to hear what others think about implementing Automation in VB.Net (if someone else has tested it and it's bad news, it would be good to know).

Comment: @mvaculisteanu : You could use an application like Notepad++ to search through all your designer files and replace `Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form` with `Inherits YourBaseForm` in one click. Visual Studio also supports this via its search box (`CTRL + F` in code editor), only it doesn't let you filter which files to search in.

Comment: @Jimi : The OP's question doesn't specify that he doesn't want to change the existing forms (though now he stated it in a comment), only that he doesn't want to manually put an event handler in each. The post is also contradicting itself: _"I don't want to **manually put a event handler** in every form (...) **Something like a overloaded load event that adds a handler on the resize event**"_ - If he wants a load event to apply to all forms, inheritance is the safest way to go. || It's an interesting thought you have though and I'm not saying it's impossible, just be sure to test it thoroughly.

Comment: @Visual Vincent: I meant that some process that automatically adds the handler at run-time. I don't want/can't afford to change the form definition.

Comment: GIve it a test drive. It looks like it's working, but there might be some quirks with VB.Net default instances. When the Forms instances are not formally disposed, some event handlers might not be unsuscribed correctly (I think).

Comment: @VisualVincent Wouldn't any changes to the designer files be overwritten when the user next opens the designer?

Comment: @ZevSpitz : No, not everything. Inheritance, for one, persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an attempt to implement an [Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation) solution to the problem.

**The problem:**
Attach one or more Event Handlers to each existing Form in a Project (or a subset of them), without editing/modifying these classes existing code.

A possible solution comes from UIAutomation, which provides means to detect when a new Window is opened and reports the event to the subscribers of its own  [Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationeventhandler), when the `EventId` of its [AutomationEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationevent?view=netframework-4.7.2) is set to a [WindowPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern) pattern.
The [AutomationElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement) member must be set to [AutomationElement.RootElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.rootelement) and the `Scope` member to [TreeScope.SubTree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.treescope).

`Automation`, for each `AutomationElement` that raises the `AutomationEvent`, reports:

- the `Element.Name` (corresponding to the Windows Title)
- the `Process ID`
- the `Window Handle` (as an Integer value)

These values are quite enough to identify a Window that belongs to the current process; the Window handle allows to identify the opened `Form` instance,  testing the [Application.OpenForms()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms) collection.

When the Form is singled out, a new `Event Handler` can be attached to an `Event` of choice.

By expanding this concept, it's possible to create a predefined List of Events and a List of Forms to attach these events to.
Possibly, with a class file to include in a Project when required.

As a note, some events will not be meaningful in this scenario, because the `Automation` reports the opening of a Window when it is already shown, thus the `Load()` and `Shown()` events belong to the past.

---

I've tested this with a couple of events (`Form.Resize()` and `Form.Activate()`), but in the code here I'm using just `.Resize()` for simplicity.

This is a graphics representation of the process.
Starting the application, the Event Handler is not attached to the `.Resize()` event.
It's just because a `Boolean` fields is set to `False`.
Clicking a Button, the `Boolean` field is set to `True`, enabling the registration of the Event Handler.
When the `.Resize()` event is registered, all Forms' Title will report the current size of the Window.

[image: Global Handlers]

**Test environment**:
`Visual Studio 2017 pro 15.7.5`
`.Net FrameWork 4.7.1`

**Imported Namespaces:**
`System.Windows.Automation`

**Reference Assemblies**:
`UIAutomationClient`
`UIAutomationTypes`

`MainForm` code:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Automation

Public Class MainForm

    Friend GlobalHandlerEnabled As Boolean = False
    Protected Friend FormsHandler As List(Of Form) = New List(Of Form)
    Protected Friend ResizeHandler As EventHandler

    Public Sub New()

        InitializeComponent()

        ResizeHandler =
                Sub(obj, args)
                    Dim CurrentForm As Form = TryCast(obj, Form)
                    CurrentForm.Text = CurrentForm.Text.Split({" ("}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0) &
                                                               $" ({CurrentForm.Width}, {CurrentForm.Height})"
                End Sub

        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
                TreeScope.Subtree,
                    Sub(UIElm, evt)
                        If Not GlobalHandlerEnabled Then Return
                        Dim element As AutomationElement = TryCast(UIElm, AutomationElement)
                        If element Is Nothing Then Return

                        Dim NativeHandle As IntPtr = CType(element.Current.NativeWindowHandle, IntPtr)
                        Dim ProcessId As Integer = element.Current.ProcessId
                        If ProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id Then
                            Dim CurrentForm As Form = Nothing
                            Invoke(New MethodInvoker(
                                Sub()
                                    CurrentForm = Application.OpenForms.
                                           OfType(Of Form)().
                                           FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Handle = NativeHandle)
                                End Sub))

                            If CurrentForm IsNot Nothing Then
                                Dim FormName As String = FormsHandler.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f?.Name = CurrentForm.Name)?.Name
                                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormName) Then
                                    RemoveHandler CurrentForm.Resize, ResizeHandler
                                    FormsHandler.Remove(FormsHandler.Where(Function(fn) fn.Name = FormName).First())
                                End If
                                Invoke(New MethodInvoker(
                                Sub()
                                    CurrentForm.Text = CurrentForm.Text & $" ({CurrentForm.Width}, {CurrentForm.Height})"
                                End Sub))

                                AddHandler CurrentForm.Resize, ResizeHandler
                                FormsHandler.Add(CurrentForm)
                            End If
                        End If
                    End Sub)
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnOpenForm_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenForm.Click
        Form2.Show(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEnableHandlers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnableHandlers.Click
        GlobalHandlerEnabled = True
        Me.Hide()
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisableHandlers_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisableHandlers.Click
        GlobalHandlerEnabled = False
        If FormsHandler IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each Item As Form In FormsHandler
                RemoveHandler Item.Resize, ResizeHandler
                Item = Nothing
            Next
        End If
        FormsHandler = New List(Of Form)
        Me.Text = Me.Text.Split({" ("}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)(0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Note:**
This previous code is  placed inside the app Starting Form (for testing), but it might be preferable to have a Module to include in the Project when needed, without touching the current code.

To get this to work, add a new Module (named `Program`) which contains a `Public Sub Main()`, and change the Project properties to start the application from `Sub Main()` instead of a Form.
Remove the check mark on `Use Application Framework` and choose `Sub Main` from the `Startup object` Combo.

All the code can be transferred to the `Sub Main` proc with a couple of modifications:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Windows
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Automation

Module Program

    Friend GlobalHandlerEnabled As Boolean = True
    Friend FormsHandler As List(Of Form) = New List(Of Form)
    Friend ResizeHandler As EventHandler

    Public Sub Main()

        Application.EnableVisualStyles()
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

        Dim MyMainForm As MainForm = New MainForm()

        ResizeHandler =
                Sub(obj, args)
                    Dim CurrentForm As Form = TryCast(obj, Form)
                    CurrentForm.Text = CurrentForm.Text.Split({" ("}, StringSplitOptions.None)(0) &
                                                               $" ({CurrentForm.Width}, {CurrentForm.Height})"
                End Sub

        Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(WindowPattern.WindowOpenedEvent,
            AutomationElement.RootElement,
                TreeScope.Subtree,
                    Sub(UIElm, evt)
                        If Not GlobalHandlerEnabled Then Return
                        Dim element As AutomationElement = TryCast(UIElm, AutomationElement)
                        If element Is Nothing Then Return

                        Dim NativeHandle As IntPtr = CType(element.Current.NativeWindowHandle, IntPtr)
                        Dim ProcessId As Integer = element.Current.ProcessId
                        If ProcessId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id Then
                            Dim CurrentForm As Form = Nothing
                            If Not MyMainForm.IsHandleCreated Then Return
                            MyMainForm.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(
                                Sub()
                                    CurrentForm = Application.OpenForms.
                                           OfType(Of Form)().
                                           FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f.Handle = NativeHandle)
                                End Sub))
                            If CurrentForm IsNot Nothing Then
                                Dim FormName As String = FormsHandler.FirstOrDefault(Function(f) f?.Name = CurrentForm.Name)?.Name
                                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(FormName) Then
                                    RemoveHandler CurrentForm.Resize, ResizeHandler
                                    FormsHandler.Remove(FormsHandler.Where(Function(fn) fn.Name = FormName).First())
                                End If

                                AddHandler CurrentForm.Resize, ResizeHandler
                                FormsHandler.Add(CurrentForm)

                                CurrentForm.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(
                                Sub()
                                    CurrentForm.Text = CurrentForm.Text & $" ({CurrentForm.Width}, {CurrentForm.Height})"
                                End Sub))
                            End If
                        End If
                    End Sub)

        Application.Run(MyMainForm)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You sure are a guy for workarounds ;). -- _"When the Forms instances are not formally disposed, some event handlers might not be unsuscribed"_ - Can't you just unsubscribe to them manually by subscribing to the [**`FormClosed` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx) as well?

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Well, when it comes to VB(.Net) default instances, I have unresolved doubts of what will happen, when and by the hands of whom. I think this feature should go (in your code you forget an anonymous reference to a supposedly dead Form, and, insted of a healthy `NullRef`, you get a new instance of it), leaving an option for backwards compatibility for the aficionados.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.I tried yesterday Automation but I couldn't get the hang of it.

Comment: @mvaculisteanu  Mind that I've never implemented this in `VB.Net` for `WinForms`. So it's kind of an experiment (see what I wrote to @Visual Vincent). It's successfully working in a couple of programs written in different languages. If I'll find something noteworthy, I'll notify you.

Comment: I need this for testing not production. There is no need for concern in case of any hiccups. ;)

Comment: @mvaculisteanu  I've added a note about using a `Module` ( with a `Sub Main`) to include in the Project, instead of editing the start up Form. Could be useful.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this several times. It's been a better tutorial for me than everything else I found elsewhere (for an unrelated task which needed a lot of outside-the-box thinking). This and the other well-written answers like it is the reason SO is so great: understandable answers which helps not only the current user, but every person who will need it through time. Amazing. When skynet takes over, I'm betting that it'll spare you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Automation as @Jimi suggested.

You can use My.Application.OpenForms to iterate throught all opened forms, but it will not help when new form is opened.

You can create some ReportSizeForm class that inherits System.Forms.Form. And change inheritance of your forms from regular System.Windows.Forms.Form to your ReportSizeForm.