# Check if a specific window name is open

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check if a specific window name is open in VB.net by clicking a button inside a loop.

Now to problem is that everytime i click the button it says it found the window even though it isn't open

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim WinHwnd As String
    Dim loopUntil As Integer = 0

    WinHwnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "VeraCrypt")

    Do Until loopUntil = 1

        If WinHwnd = 0 Then ' Window is close
            MsgBox("Not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "not found")
        Else
            ' Window is found
            MsgBox(" found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "found")

            loopUntil = 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: You are assigning the return value of `FindWindow()` to a `String` and then check for a number: `WinHwnd = 0`. The Loop is not required. Set Option Strict On.

Comment: What did you have in mind when you set up that loop? Knowing that might help me understand how I can help.

Comment: The loop it's just one part of my program, I'm waiting for the VeraCrypt to open up so that i could make other actions after it showed up basically. I've used the delay function before that and it just didn't work out the way i wanted it to work out

Comment: [Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automation.addautomationeventhandler). Use an Automation event handler set to a `WindowPattern` pattern. This event will be raised each time a new Window is opened (any Window). Sample code here: [Add an event to all Forms in a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51491566/add-an-event-to-all-forms-in-a-project?answertab=active#tab-top). You just need the Automation Handler setup there.

Comment: My theory is that you get false positives because you have an unforeseen result in WinHwnd. This unforeseen result might be a very simple thing, like WinHwnd being equal to zero. To use `Option Strict On` would help you avoid this kind of situation. Best way to understand the false positive would be to take a look at WinHwnd in debug mode, and modify your If statement accordingly.

Comment: May I presume this window is from another application?

Comment: Yes, this window is another program.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code I used to catch when a window opens and change a text field in it.

First the loop to the method `autoFillFileSelection`:

```
    Dim timeout As Integer = WAITING_TIMEOUT_MS / 1000
    While autoFillFileSelection(curFile) = False
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

        If timeout = nbLoop Then
            enterFileIntoFormTimeout = True
            Exit While
        End If
        nbLoop += 1
    End While
```

Second, the method itself:

```
    Protected Function autoFillFileSelection(ByVal file As String) As Boolean
        ' Find program/dialog handle; 32770 je za dialog
        Dim hWnd As IntPtr
        Dim englishTitle As String = "Choose File to Upload"
        Dim frenchTitle As String = "Choisir un fichier à télécharger"
        Dim frenchTitle2 As String = "Choisir un fichier à charger"
        Dim englishButton As String = "&Open"
        Dim frenchButton As String = "&Ouvrir"
        Dim frenchButton2 As String = "Ou&vrir"

        Dim button As String = englishButton

        Dim windowClass As String = Nothing ' "#32770"
        hWnd = FindWindow(windowClass, englishTitle)
        If hWnd = 0 Then
            hWnd = FindWindow(windowClass, frenchTitle)
            If hWnd = 0 Then hWnd = FindWindow(windowClass, frenchTitle2)
            button = frenchButton
        End If

        If hWnd = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If

        'Ensure window has focus, outerwise, would wait for user to click on window (and potentially choosing another file, NO GOOD !)
        'CType(Me.ParentForm, Object).focus()
        selectWindow() ' --> Surelly useless for you as my window what coming from my software, but an IE component
        SetFocus(hWnd)

        'Write file into dialog and submit it
        Dim hWndEdit As IntPtr
        hWndEdit = apiFindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBoxEx32", "")
        Dim hWndEdit1 As IntPtr
        hWndEdit1 = apiFindWindowEx(hWndEdit, IntPtr.Zero, "ComboBox", "")
        Dim hWndEdit2 As IntPtr
        hWndEdit2 = apiFindWindowEx(hWndEdit1, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", "")
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder(file)
        Dim WM_SETTEXT As Integer = 12 '&HC 'decimalno 12
        SendMessage(hWndEdit2, WM_SETTEXT, 0, sb)
        Dim hWndTextbox As IntPtr = apiFindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", button)
        If hWndTextbox = 0 Then hWndTextbox = apiFindWindowEx(hWnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Button", frenchButton2)

        Dim BN_CLICKED As Integer = 245
        SendMessage(hWndTextbox, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero)

        Return True
    End Function
```