# How to create a notification in a text file when user starts a new application

Tags: vb.net

I am new at programming. I have been asked to create a code which will locally monitor and logs the name of the application to a text file whenever user starts or executes an application on their system. I don't have much idea about processes, can u help me please?

User stars any application, Log is saved in a text file with time and name of application.

Comment: [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) -> [WindowPattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern?view=netframework-4.7.2).[WindowOpenedEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.windowopenedevent?view=netframework-4.7.2). The WindowOpened event is raised when a new Window (any Window in the System) is created. You can follow the procedure shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505218/7444103).

Comment: Is there something like whenever an .exe file is launched i can get a notification? We are monitoring the Local System to check which applications end user will open, the name of the application are not known yet, it could be any application.

Comment: It depends. The UI Automation pattern I was referring to, catches the execution of any windowed application, even if the *window* is actually a console instance. The name of the application (along with its handle and other details) is reported by the AutomationElement that is referenced in the event arguments. Otherwise, you could (simple) poll the processes list using the Process class or use WMI events.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/desktop/WmiSdk/retrieving-a-class). Then you can monitor `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` to be notified when a process starts. Additionally you even can use `Win32_ProcessStopTrace` to be notified when a process stops.
Your code would look like that:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim startWatcher As ManagementEventWatcher = New ManagementEventWatcher(New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"))
    startWatcher.EventArrived += New EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatcher_EventArrived)
    startWatcher.Start()
End Sub


Private Shared Sub startWatcher_EventArrived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArrivedEventArgs)
    Dim logString As String ="{0}: Process started: {1}".Format( Now.ToString(), e.NewEvent.Properties("ProcessName").Value)
     Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(YourLogFile)
            sw.WriteLine(logString)
     End Using
End Sub
```