# Add event to load event of forms at run time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events, automation

I'm trying to figure out a way to, at run time, add an event handler to the load event of forms in the project at run time so we dont to go into the 100+ forms we have in the solution and add it manually or risk other devs forgetting to do it for future forms.

The reason being is when the form is loaded I need a to run a procedure to load user default grids,settings and other items every time they open a form.

I've previously tried to use the Automation with varied success however it does not work all the time. 
I've researched for the past few weeks for ways to procced with no success, so i'm at a brick wall right now.

Comment: " go into the 100+ forms we have in the solution and add it manually" - should be faster than "researched for the past few weeks". it only takes time once, which is better than make the app start slower *every* time for *every* user. "devs forgetting to do" - write a tool which will inspect source codes and fix or at least report missing code

Comment: Why not create an interface, implement this interface in a new class that derives from `Form`? Then every form you create, inherit from this new form and the interface would take care of all this... Or create a base class to handle this and every `Form` you create use this base class? There are more than a few ways to accomplish this, please update post with specifics you have tried, what isn't working so we can help you out.

Comment: Could you please post your code, whatever you tried so far?

Comment: Try this: [Add an event to all Forms in a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505218/7444103) if you haven't, it adds an event handler to any Form in the application when the Form is created. Since it uses UIAutomation, you cannot *hook* the `Load` event. `Activate` and `Shown` may not be reliable either, but there are other events that can be used for this. Even if it's a *repeated* event, you can remove the handler after the code you need to run is done. Read the notes about the Module version. Anyway, you should have a class that handles the instantiation of your Forms or a template.

Comment: Note, however, that this *procedure* is meant for testing, not production. IMO, you should take the time perform the necessary modifications to the application / application templates, to manage your Window *models* in a single *place*.

Comment: I had previously looked into and tested the suggestion from Jimi, however it did not quiet do what i wanted. Judging from the feedback from you guys I think it is best i approach it properly as suggested and then sort out a tool to catch anything that is missed. Cheers advise guys.