# How do I determine if any of the forms of may application is active?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have received a peculiar request from a client for whom I have made a vb.net desktop application. He needs to log how much time is spent using the application. With "application" in use I mean that any of its forms (modal or otherwise) is active and that the application is not just running in the background or minimized. Is there way to tell if any of the forms belonging to the application are active? Once I figure out that, I think I can find a way to log the "active" time.

Comment: There's no magic. Handle the appropriate events to know when form states change and track whether there is at least one form active or not.

Comment: The `Activated` and `Deactivate` events are raised when a Form is show or gets the focus and when it's closed or the focus passes to another Form/app (by direct user action or because it's minimized). It doesn't mean that it's *used*, though.

Comment: So, therefore there is no other way than putting code in each and every form. I was hoping that I could iterate through the My.Application.OpenForms object collection and somehow tell if anyone of them is active.

Comment: If you don't want to poll the collection - but you can just check the `ActiveForm` property - you can use something like this: [Add an event to all Forms in a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51505218/7444103). It adds event handlers to any Form when it's opened and removes the handlers when a Form is closed. It can be *attached* to any existing application without changing a single line of code in the app.

Comment: Well, except you need to *inject* that code, of course. You could do the same with an external application that monitors the other one, using UI Automation. Or an UI Automation helper library.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi I think I will stick to adding a "Activated" and "Deactivate" sub to every form. However I will try to do it on the fly by using a routine that does a addhandler on each open form. Will repeat the process every time a form is deactivated, because that could mean that a new form has been opened. If no new form is opened, and focus is returned to the calling form, I would still run the addhandler routine. I don't suppose there is a downside to re-adding the same handler to the same form.

Comment: Add the handlers just **once**. If you add a new handler, when the event is raised, all existing handlers will be called and you'll run the same code over and over. Maybe give the code I linked a shot. The notes there should give you a quick start; if you can survive all the blabbering, that is.

Comment: Is there a way to determine if a handler has already been added?

Comment: It's complicated. The first thing you do is not to add a second handler. It should be easy enough, since you're the one adding it. Otherwise, you can remove the handler before adding a new one. It doesn't matter if there are no handlers already. My suggestion is to add one handler when it's needed. You can use a support class that supervises the creation of all the Form, adds the handlers and updates the logs when these *extra* events are raised. Thus, you'd have just one class that does all the work. You won't even need to add the handlers directly to a Form class (you shouldn't, anyway).

Comment: It is much simpler to determine whether user interaction is taking place with your application as opposed to the this nightmare of monitoring form status.  If you are interested, I could post some code.

Comment: I would be interested @TnTinMn . Monitoring if a form is active is not even the best solution since it could be open and the user be away from keyboard and it would still show as active. I would need a way to detect mouse/keyboard interaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monitoring keyboard and mouse activity in a WinForm project can achieved by using a class that implements the [IMessageFilter Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8) and installing an instance of this class using the [Application.AddMessageFilter(IMessageFilter) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.addmessagefilter?view=netframework-4.8).  Note that only messages posted to the thread's message queue can be detected this way; luckily all keyboard and mouse messages are posted to this queue. (For more info, see:[About Messages and Message Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues).

The following is an implementation of `IMessageFilter` designed to provide the time that the application is receiving user input (the `TimeUsed` property). The class constructor (`Sub New`) takes the parameter `idleSecondsToIgnore`.  This parameter is used to allow used time to accumulate while there is no user input;  think of it as a grace period to account for the time the user is viewing the application while not actively interacting with it.  The constructor also handles registering the filter.

```
Public Class UsageMonitor : Implements IMessageFilter

  Private timeUsedTicksAccumulator As Int64
  Private lastActiveTime As DateTime
  Private appIsRunning As Boolean
  Private ReadOnly idleTicksToIgnore As Int64

  Public Sub New(idleSecondsToIgnore As Int32)
    Me.idleTicksToIgnore = TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond * idleSecondsToIgnore
    StartTime = DateTime.Now
    lastActiveTime = StartTime
    Application.AddMessageFilter(Me)
    AddHandler Application.ApplicationExit, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                              appIsRunning = False
                                              UpdateTimeUsed()
                                              Me._EndTime = DateAndTime.Now
                                            End Sub
    appIsRunning = True
  End Sub

  Public ReadOnly Property StartTime As DateTime
  Public ReadOnly Property EndTime As DateTime

  Public ReadOnly Property TotalRunTime As TimeSpan
    Get
      Return If(appIsRunning, DateTime.Now, EndTime) - StartTime
    End Get
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property TimeUsed As TimeSpan
    Get
      Dim ticks As Int64 = timeUsedTicksAccumulator
      If appIsRunning Then
        Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
        Dim diff As TimeSpan = now - lastActiveTime
        If diff.Ticks < idleTicksToIgnore Then
          ticks += diff.Ticks
        Else
          ' give usage credit for only the idle time threshold
          ticks += idleTicksToIgnore
        End If
      End If
      Return New TimeSpan(ticks)
    End Get
  End Property

  Public Function PreFilterMessage(ByRef m As Message) As Boolean Implements IMessageFilter.PreFilterMessage
    ' Only messages posted to the thread message queue are received by this method.
    ' i.e. only messages that are processed by the message pump loop

    ' From: Message Routing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#message-routing
    '   A message that is posted to a message queue is called a queued message. 
    '   These are primarily the result of user input entered through the mouse or keyboard, 
    '   such as WM_MOUSEMOVE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, and WM_CHAR messages. 
    '   Other queued messages include the timer, paint, and quit messages: WM_TIMER, 
    '   WM_PAINT, and WM_QUIT. Most other messages, which are sent directly to a 
    '   window procedure, are called nonqueued messages.


    Const WM_KEYFIRST As Int32 = &H100
    Const WM_KEYLAST As Int32 = &H108

    Const WM_MOUSEFIRST As Int32 = &H200
    Const WM_MOUSELAST As Int32 = &H20E

    Const WM_NCMOUSEMOVE As Int32 = &HA0
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN As Int32 = &HA1
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONUP As Int32 = &HA2
    Const WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK As Int32 = &HA3
    Const WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN As Int32 = &HA4
    Const WM_NCRBUTTONUP As Int32 = &HA5
    Const WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK As Int32 = &HA6
    Const WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN As Int32 = &HA7
    Const WM_NCMBUTTONUP As Int32 = &HA8
    Const WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK As Int32 = &HA9

    Const WM_NCMOUSEHOVER As Int32 = &H2A0
    Const WM_NCMOUSELEAVE As Int32 = &H2A2

    Select Case m.Msg
      Case WM_KEYFIRST To WM_KEYLAST
        UpdateTimeUsed()
      Case WM_MOUSEFIRST To WM_MOUSELAST
        UpdateTimeUsed()
      Case WM_NCMOUSEMOVE, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCLBUTTONUP, WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCRBUTTONUP, WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK, WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN, WM_NCMBUTTONUP, WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK
        UpdateTimeUsed()
      Case WM_NCMOUSEHOVER, WM_NCMOUSELEAVE
        UpdateTimeUsed()
      Case Else
        'ignore it
    End Select


    Return False ' always return false as we are not handling the message per se
  End Function

  Private Sub UpdateTimeUsed()
    Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim diff As TimeSpan = now - lastActiveTime
    If diff.Ticks < idleTicksToIgnore Then
      timeUsedTicksAccumulator += diff.Ticks
    Else
      ' give usage credit for only the idle time threshold
      timeUsedTicksAccumulator += idleTicksToIgnore
    End If
    lastActiveTime = now
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return $"Monitoring Started: {StartTime}{vbCrLf}Tot. Time: {Fmt(TotalRunTime)}{vbCrLf}Time Active: {Fmt(TimeUsed)}"
  End Function

  Private Shared Function Fmt(ts As TimeSpan) As String
    Return $"{ts:dd} Days {ts:hh}:{ts:mm}:{ts:ss}.{ts:fff}"
  End Function
End Class
```

The place to create an instance of this class is right before the first form is created and shown to the user.  If you are using VB.Net's Application Framework, you can add it to definition of the `MyApplication` class (accessible from the Project Menu->Project Properties->Application Tab->View Application Events button that opens the ApplicationEvents.vb file.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My
  Partial Friend Class MyApplication
    Public ReadOnly Property Usage As UsageMonitor = New UsageMonitor(600) ' 10 minute idle

    Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
      ' add your logging code here 
    End Sub
  End Class
End Namespace
```

In the above code, the instance is created via the `Usage` property.

If you use a `Sub Main` to start the application, create an instance of `UsageMonitor` before calling `Application.Run(mainform)`.

To give this a test, create a new WinForm project and place a Label on the form (also add the code shown above to the project).  Then modify the Form1.vb file as follows.

```
Public Class Form1
  Private WithEvents Timer1 As Timer

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1 = New Timer
    Timer1.Interval = 2000
    Timer1.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = My.Application.Usage.ToString()
  End Sub
End Class
```

Note that you may want to decrease the value of `idleSecondsToIgnore` from 600 to 10 for testing so that you can observe the active time value stop increasing when you stop user interaction (moving the mouse over the form).

Comment: Hi there. Does this run in a x86 machine? Maybe you just need `Integer` instead of `Int32` and `Int64`?

Comment: @JQSOFT, Int64 is the proper type for the [TimeSpan(Int64)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_TimeSpan__ctor_System_Int64_) constructor.  It is fully supported in both 32 and 64 bit .Net.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Comment: Will see how I can adapt it for my application. Thanks!